# Why do these print() calls appear to execute in the wrong order?

Tags: python, python-3.x

weird.py:

```
import sys

def f ():
    print('f', end = '')
    g()

def g ():
    1 / 0

try:
    f()
except:
    print('toplevel', file = sys.stderr)
```

Python session:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import weird
toplevel
f>>>
```

Why does "toplevel" print before "f"?

This doesn't happen if the `end = ''` or the `file = sys.stderr` are removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because stdout and stderr are *line buffered*. They buffer characters and only flush when you have a complete line.

By setting `end=''` you ensure there is no complete line and the buffer isn't flushed until *later* when the Python interactive interpreter outputs `>>>` and flushes the buffer explicitly.

If you remove `file=sys.stderr` you output to `sys.stdout` again, and you printed `toplevel\n` as `print()` adds a newline, thus flushing the `sys.stdout` buffer.

You can explicitly force a flush by setting the `flush=True` argument to the `print()` function (Python 3.3 and up) or by calling `sys.stdout.flush()`.

Comment: Afaik, In older python versions you can use the `-u` argument which forces stderr to be *totally unbuffered*. (Just as a note. I know that the OPis using 3.4)

Comment: @BhargavRao: The option is [still there in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).